# programe stuck in main java threading

Tags: java, multithreading

When i run the following programe it's not coming out from the main

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Ui1 implements Runnable {

    private Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ui1 ui1 = new Ui1();

        Thread t = new Thread(ui1);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ui1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(ui1);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(ui1);

        t.start();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }

    final String getUID() {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(uuid);
        return builder.toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            String s = getUID();

            if (!set.add(s)) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**when i reduce the iteration from 1000 to 100 the mains exits properly**

This is the  Threaddump

```
2014-04-09 14:42:16
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b703d800 nid=0x1903 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Thread-1" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b400d000 nid=0x5903 runnable [0x0000000117d0e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:498)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
    at Ui1.run(Ui1.java:40)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b5843000 nid=0x5303 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b5033000 nid=0x5103 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b400a000 nid=0x4f03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b502d000 nid=0x4d03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b5841000 nid=0x3903 in Object.wait() [0x0000000117455000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007aaa85568> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000007aaa85568> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b583e800 nid=0x3703 in Object.wait() [0x0000000117352000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007aaa850f0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000007aaa850f0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b583d800 nid=0x3503 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b5013800 nid=0x2503 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b5014800 nid=0x2703 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b4802000 nid=0x2903 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b4802800 nid=0x2b03 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b5015000 nid=0x2d03 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b5015800 nid=0x2f03 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b5016000 nid=0x3103 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b5800000 nid=0x3303 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007f84b5843800 nid=0x5503 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 135

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 76800K, used 13210K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007b0000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 66048K, 20% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007ab766930,0x00000007aeb00000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000007af580000,0x00000007af580000,0x00000007b0000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000007aeb00000,0x00000007aeb00000,0x00000007af580000)
 ParOldGen       total 174592K, used 0K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000070aa80000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 174592K, 0% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000700000000,0x000000070aa80000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 2939K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x00000006fc300000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 21504K, 13% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006fb0def18,0x00000006fc300000)
```

Comment: `HashSet` is not thread safe; this said, it is strange that you get this error and not a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Anyway, quick fix: use a `CopyOnWriteArraySet` or a `Collections.synchronized()` of your `HashSet`.

Comment: the error is not reproducable

Comment: @fge Thanks CopyOnWriteArraySet works fine no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this (not 100% of the times). As **fge** says, HashSet isn't thread safe, and you shouldn't access it from different threads. The results of doing so are unpredictable.

Anyway, trying to explain this specific pathology, I suspect that the internal hashtable structure becomes broken. It looks like due to the race condition between threads, the linked lists in the buckets become circular. In this situation, a put operation continues looking for the key in the list indefinitely, and this is what causes the program to get stuck.

Note that in order to reproduce the problem I added join() commands on all threads, otherwise the main thread terminates and all threads are then terminated as well.

In order to fix the problem, you may use one of the following:

- ConcurrentHashMap - very efficient for multiple threads.
- Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet()) - Wraps your set and makes all set operations mutually exclusive.
- CopyOnWriteArraySet - Very efficient if there are many reads and a few writes
- Synchronize the access to get() and put() yourself - This is useful if you need additional operations to be done atomically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Set set = new HashSet(); is being written from multiple threads.

There are few ways to overcome this situation:

- I think best: avoid concurrent writing (use different sets in
  different threads, then merge results)
- Use ConcurrentHashSet. At least read performance is way better than Collections.synchronized() (which may be an option)
- Extract !set.add(s) to another method and use keyword synchronized. (you may synchronize on your set variable, but synchronization on
  another method would provide better granularity)

As I said, in my opinion best thing would be design application with as less as possible shared data between the threads.